# mySQL select top item has most child in one table?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table as follows:

**id    name     birthday     sex     parent**

With **parent** is value of **id**, such as i have 3 records:

record 1:     **1     'dad'     '1960-10-10'     0     0**

record 2:     **2     'son'     '2000-05-05'     0     1**

record 3:    **3     'daughter'   '2004-03-05'   1     1**

Record 2,3 is child of record 1. How can i select top item that has most child and order by DESC. Thanks.

Comment: Some pseudo-code to get you started: `SELECT count(id) AS children FROM table GROUP BY parent WHERE parent <> 0 ORDER BY count(id) DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: It's a good idea to add one more column for child count of each entry for this problem and future use.

Comment: @AmirNoori I would have mitigate opinion about that idea. Adding a 'count' column means that you have to keep that column in sync with actual values.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, no big deal, each time you create or delete  an entry you update the parent, since we rarely create or delete this kind of tables.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, I'm not saying you'r wrong but having extra info doesn't hurt :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can i select top item that has most child

This is a basic application of the `GROUP BY` clause + `COUNT()` aggregate function.

This will group all children together (according to `parent`) and count them. Finally, they are ordered according to that count:

```sql
SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS c FROM tbl 
  WHERE parent != 0 -- ignore "no parent"
  GROUP BY(parent) 
  ORDER BY c DESC;
```